# What is $ \lim_{x \to 0} \log_0(x) $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms

As per the title; what is $ \lim_{x \to 0} \log_0(x) $ ?

According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x-%3E0+of+log_0%28x%29): $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \log_0(x) = 0 $$ but how is this possible?

Surely the limit should be indeterminate since $\log_0(x) = \frac{\log(x)}{\log(0)} $ and $ \log(0) = $ indeterminate?

Comment: As $X\to 0$ , $ln(X)\to-\infty$. So now we use the change of base formula, $log_a(X)=\frac{ln(X)}{ln(a)}$, thus $lim_{a\to 0}log_a(X)=lim_{a\to 0}\frac{ln(X)}{ln(a)}=0$

Comment: What does $\log_0(x)$ mean? You have to have this make sense before you can work on this limit.

Comment: @alex.jordan $log_0$ does not mean anything as far as I can tell, but $log_a$ does for any $a$ no matter how close to zero, so it makes sense to speak of the limit.

Comment: If I understand you, then the limit would be $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\log_x(x)$, not $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\log_0(x)$.

Comment: $\log_0(x)$ asks the question "what must we raise $0$ to, to get $x$?" So $\log_0(x)$ is undefined everywhere, except by many people's convention, at $x=1$, where $\log_0(1)=0$.

Comment: I accidentally turned it into something that makes more sense to me.

Comment: Log to the base $0$? Got to be kidding. It may be interesting (though, it seems, not particularly challenging) to get Alpha to do something stupid.

Comment: +1 For finding a ridiculous output from WA. How does WA explain this in its "step by step" solution? I don't care to sign up for that feature, but apparently you can get three such things free each day.

Comment: Let us let the OP the opportunity to do the explaining for $\,\log_0x\,$, shall we? On first (and second, and third...) sight this is a nonsense, but let's give her/him a little slack and wait for him to make us the favour to clear out what he/she means...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\log_0 x$ cannot exist unless $\log_0 x$ exists for $x$ in some open neighborhood of $0$, with the possible exception of $x=0$.  (Since the argument $x$ must be positive, we can take "open neighborhood of $0$" to mean a set of the form $[0,\varepsilon)$ where $\varepsilon>0$.)

**Later edit:** I suspect what's going on is something like this:
$$
\log_\varepsilon x = \frac{\log x}{\log\varepsilon},
$$
then letting $\varepsilon\downarrow0$, we have the denominator going to $-\infty$, so that the fraction approaches $0$.  Hence $\log_0 x$ gets construed to be $0$, and then one lets $x$ go to $0$, and the limit is $0$.

Comment: The function $\log_0(X)$ is continuous on it's very limited domain.

Comment: But it's very limited domain is far from $0$.

Comment: @BabyDragon : Its very limited domain is empty, and it is indeed continuous at every point in its domain.  But could you write $\log_0$ instead of $log_0$?  Just use a backslash, thus: \log_0.  This not only prevents italicization, but also provides proper spacing before and after "$\log$" in expressions like $a\log b$.  Similarly \sin, \cos, \min, \max, \det, \inf, \sup, \lim, etc.

Comment: I was referring to the part of the statement where you say "with the possible exception of $x=0$", if we choose to take this convention.

Comment: This is irrelevant, but there are conventions where "$\log_0$" would have a singleton domain of $\{1\}$. It's the same convention that regards $x^0$ as an everywhere-defined function equal to $1$, even at $0^0$.

Comment: @BabyDragon : Also, you should distinguish between capital $X$ and lower-case $x$.

Comment: @alex.jordan : This proposed conventional domain I'll have to think about.

Comment: @alex.jordan : I think the equality $0^0=1$ is not merely a convention.  But I don't know if anyone's every argued the case for that statement.  Maybe I should see if I can write it out and publish it.

Comment: The justification I have seen for this is that the number of functions from an $n$ element set to an $m$ element set is $m^n$. The number of functions from the empty set to the empty set in one thus, $0^0=1$.

Comment: It depends on the definition of $a^b$. If, for natural numbers $b$, it is $\prod_{i=1}^ba$, then $0^0$ is $1$ for sure as an empty product. But I just meant to say that if you accept $0^0=1$, then I guess you would accept $\log_0(1)=0$.

Comment: It can also be justified by saying it's an empty product.  Multiplying by no numbers at all is the same as multiplying by $1$.  Also, the identity $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z^n/n!)$ doesn't work when $z=0$ unless $0^0=1$, since the first term is $0^0/0!$.  And the Poisson distribution with parameter value $0$ would also fail to be what it obviously ought to be.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Regarding $0^0=1$, see for example Knuth's "Two Notes on Notation", Amer. Math. Monthly, May 1992 (in particular the top of p. 408).

Comment: The explanation provided in your later edit makes the most sense regarding what is happening here.

Comment: @HansLundmark : Thank you.  I think I've seen that paper before, but I don't remember anything about it.